# Java- How to split and ignore a String having this special character

Tags: java, java-8

This might be simple thing. But I am trying out for the best solution. Can someone help me with this in Java or Java 8 ?

**Question**
I have a String URL `/api/data/stiffers:stiffer-state/stiffer=monkey-king 0/1?fields=(status;statistics;speed)`.  I want to split this by character '/' but `stiffer=monkey-king 0/1` should not be splitted. Because it also has a character '/'.

Can some one help me with the code ?

To be more clear, the output should be

api
data
stiffers:stiffer-state
stiffer=monkey-king 0/1?fields=(status;statistics;speed)

Comment: Sorry but `Because it also has a character '/'` is unclear (at least to me). Where does it have it?

Comment: if you always have numbers surrounding this / and never other slashes you can use a regex to check for number before and after /

Comment: If there are fixed number of `/`, say k, before `stiffer=monkey-king 0/1`, then you can try `string.split("/", k+1);` to split on only first k occurrences of `/`.

Comment: RE update: we know which `/` you don't want to split on, we don't know *why* this one. What rules did you use to determine that?

Comment: Off-topic-comment: don't use `<br>` in your code, use two spaces and line break (return/enter key) instead.

Comment: You can use `split()` with a regular expression - I would suggest using a regular expression with negative lookahead, like `\/(?!0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `/` should not follow a digit and only then it counts as a delimiter:

```
 Arrays.stream(test.split("/(?!\\d)")).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: we don't really need to escape `/`  in this case, so `\\/(?!\\d)` could be just `/(?!\\d)`

Comment: If `/` follows a character ? One hint there is always `=` symbol in the string which we don't want to split `/`.